# Error with plugin updating in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I hope all is well with you
It is about a week I have problem with updating plugins and themes but this problem does not affect all plugins but some of them. When I press the update button at the next page I get "Not Available" error. 
Here is the screen shot of this. How can I fix the problem? 
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D33pA.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear related to programming, but just general use of WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you ,Deactivate all other plugins except which you want to update then update check with this if is not working then revert to a core WordPress theme (eg, twentysixteen) and check if you see the same problem.
If problem goes away then you can find due to what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Habiballah Hezarehee

Please check if there is dose't available any update for installed plugins in this case have got this type of screen. If you have any plugin update in pending please share those plugin detail maybe it's very help full for someone to putt an answer.